How read excel file format in pyspark databricks notebook
How to read the xlsx file format in azure databricks notebook with pyspark programming. we are tried as below code but getting error.
import pandas as pd
spark.createDataFrame(pd.read_excel("/Volumes/test/vls/data/empty data.xlsx"))

is it possible without external library to access the xlsx format?
error :
PySparkTypeError: Exception thrown when converting pandas.Series (object) with name

Have you tried any approach? Please add those details and blockers facing.

non of the solutions not working

Below are possible approaches without installing external library
Use pandas and create spark dataframe.
Below is the sample code.
import pandas as pd

spark.createDataFrame(pd.read_excel("path_to_excel_file/sample5000.xlsx")).display()

Output:



Unnamed: 0
First Name
Last Name
Gender
Country
Age
Date
Id




1
Dulce
Abril
Female
United States
32
15/10/2017
1562


2
Mara
Hashimoto
Female
Great Britain
25
16/08/2016
1582


3
Philip
Gent
Male
France
36
21/05/2015
2587


4
Kathleen
Hanner
Female
United States
25
15/10/2017
3549




or
import pyspark

pyspark.pandas.read_excel("file:/<file_path>/sample5000.xlsx").display()

If you don't want to use pandas then only way is to install
com.crealytics.spark.excel library in cluster.

Hi All, I have tried your samples but not working .... PySparkTypeError: Exception thrown when converting pandas.Series (object) with name 'PCV size' to Arrow Array (None).

installed lib pip install fsspec ,  pip install openpyxl

are you using pandas or pyspark.pandas or com.crealytics.spark.excel?

Please add you code in question mentioning edit.
